# How can I use the Wronskian to show the following relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, scattering

[image: **enter image description here**]

I cannot solve the part(a) and (b) mathematically.
Have no idea how to start solving the problem by using the property of wronskian.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Do you know what is the Wronskian and it's properties?

Comment: All I know is that the wronskian is a determinant used to test the linear independence of the solution from the differential equation. I know that when I take the derivative on the wronskian, I can represent the wronskian in term of another wronskian with another variable multiplying with exponential factor containing the integration of p(x) in the upper index. ( W(x)=W(y)exp(int(p(x)))  ) I don't know how can I use this things to prove the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recognize this problem! It's from my book. I do know that the OP is not in my class at the moment as it only meets in the fall.  A hint: the point of the problem is that $W(y_1(x), y_2(x))$  is independent of position, and hence the same on the left and right of the scatterer.

Comment: I've already solve the part(a) problem. I use the truth that the wave function conjugate is still the solution of Schrödinger equation so I construct the wronskian which is (1(),1()*). Then, as you said, I proved that the wronskian is independent to the position, since the Schrödinger equation is independent to the first derivative (the exponent is vanishing) . Eventually, by equating the wronskian from left and right, I obtain the answer.